# How can I get my Code Igniter route to work in our AWS web host

Tags: php, codeigniter, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

We are moving our website from our current web host to AWS. The website was outsourced to a third party developer and was turned over to me. On checking the codes, I saw that it was done in Code Igniter.

I've uploaded the website to an instance in AWS for parallel running with the current web host:

- the web site in the current host is accessed on URL www.oursite.com
- the AWS instance is accessed on url ec2-our-instance.compute.amazonaws.com

I've made sure that the AWS database connection is working. In one config files, I've adjusted the base URL:

```
function baseUrl(){
    //$base ='http://www.oursite.com/';

    $base = 'http://ec2-our-instance.compute.amazonaws.com/';

    return $base;
}
```

Calling the baseURL() returns our AWS instance URL.

My problem now is that the website calls functions in a file, site_info.php via routing the filename, function and parameters in the URL.

The directory of the function file is listed below:

```
\site\application\controllers\site_info.php
```

One function in site_info.php is:

```
function showWorld(){
    echo 'Hello World';
}
```

The cURL call to showWorld() has the URL set to the route of the function, i.e. baseURL().'/site/site_info/showWorld'. The code is listed below:

```
function showSomething(){
    $url = baseURL().'/site/site_info/showWorld';

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,120); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS, 200);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT , 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url ); 
}

showSomething();
```

The call to function showSomething() echos the content on the currently hosted website, i.e. www.oursite.com. I can even run on the browser the URL, www.oursite.com/site/site_info/showWorld and get the echo content.

The AWS hosted site returns the error 'The requested URL /site/site_info/showWorld was not found on this server.'

How do I correct this?

Comment: I'm not CI expert, but I see that your `baseURL()` returns nothing. Make sure it returns absolute URL and not relative.

Comment: Where do you define baseUrl()? In the same controller as showsomething()?

Answer (score 0):

```
Just Define in your root/application/config/config.php
$config['base_url'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME'].'://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/";

call like this

function showSomething(){
    $url = base_url(true).'site/site_info/showWorld';

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,120); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS, 200);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT , 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url ); 
}

showSomething();
```